# What does a mirrorlog do in LVM mirroring?

Tags: lvm

http://www.tcpdump.com/kb/os/linux/lvm-mirroring/intro.html

states that when mirroring a Logical Volume in LVM we need a "A volume for the log "... ehh, what exactly is a mirror log? Is it always recommended when mirroring an LV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [LVM documentation](http://vr.org/docs/centos/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/LV_create.html) which comes up easily on [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lvm+mirror+log&l=1):

> LVM maintains a small log which it uses to keep track of which regions are in sync with the mirror or mirrors. By default, this log is kept on disk, which keeps it persistent across reboots. You can specify instead that this log be kept in memory with the --corelog argument; this eliminates the need for an extra log device, but it requires that the entire mirror be resynchronized at every reboot.

Ok, I can understand why this would not be clear if you don't have a little background in filesystems or failure tolerance, but you should have at least done minimum research and found the explanation above.

The issue is what happens if there is a system crash or power failure when the system has written some new data to one of the disks but not to the other. The log keeps track of which areas of each component of the mirror have not yet been written to one of the disks. If the log is non-empty at some point in time, it means the disks are out of synch. If the log is kept in memory, then when the system boots, it needs to read every block from both disks and check for discrepancies. If the log is kept on the disk, then the system only needs to read the log and check the blocks mentioned in the log.

Answer (score 1):

This keeps the state of the mirror i.e. which blocks have not been synced yet. This is also the reason why I dislike LVM for RAID1. You need 3 volumes to mirror. With mdadm this is solved by putting an (optional) bitmap onto the device (or to an external device). With small devices a full sync does not hurt. With big devices it hurts - so better put an ("internal") bitmap there.

Comment: I believe one can put the mirror log on one of the mirror disk but there is a performance hit for doing this.